# tag: cryptography vs security

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The question [Break an authentication protocol based on a pre-shared symmetric key](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/431/157)
 was tagged with both [cryptography](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) and [security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security).

What is the difference between these tags, and when should each be used?

Comment: I retagged the question as "crypto" only, according to my answer below.

Comment: [tag:security] is far more general than [tag:cryptography].

Answer (score 5):

My stand on it is similar to the distinction between crypto.SE and ITsecurity.SE (which is slightly vague and sometime ambiguous)

[cryptography](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) is for more theoretical primitives , algorithms and methods and the their analysis. (e.g, AES, ZK-proofs, signature schemes, etc.)

[security](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) is for security in real-world systems and practical questions.(e.g., computer forensics, DDS and network security, etc.)

Comment: I think the main point is that security is way broader than crypto.

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't sure what to use. I'm not too keen on [protocols](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocols) here either, but I do want have a way to distinguish mathematical primitives from abstract cryptography. How about [abstract-cryptography](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-cryptography), for that matter?

Comment: can you explain what abstract-crypto will include?

Comment: @RanG. I've heard it used for the study of protocols in which crypto primitives are treated as black boxes (“$E$ is symmetric encryption algorithm, $H$ is a hash, …”). I don't know how widespread this terminology is.

Comment: this is just plain theoretical cryptography: assuming one-way functions, (good) encryptoin schemes, etc.  I don't see the need to call it theoretical-cryptography

Comment: see [this](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/faq.html#no). But I don't think there is need to have separate crypto tags for these. (ps: abstract crpto is a very bad name.)

Comment: If anything protocols should be cryptographic-protocols. Abstract-cryptography seems to be going too fine-grained.